# csvsimple handles underscores wrong

Tags: input-encodings, csv, csvsimple

I try to print a `.csv` file using `csvsimple`. The column headers of that CSV file contain underscores.

Within the `csvsimple` documentation, I found the option `respect underscore=true` option that is supposed to make LaTeX handle the underscores correctly.

So far, my code can be compiled, but the underscores are rendered in the pdf as an unknown character:

[image: Illustration of wrong underscore handling.]

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \csvautobooktabular[respect underscore=true]{data.csv}

\end{document}
```

And here the respective CSV file:

```
test_col,col_test
1824,4
1892,3
1948,3
1968,3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The default OT1 encoding doesn't have ascii symbols in the places you might expect.