# Importing csv Table with Underscores

Tags: csvsimple, underscore

I have to import a csv table whose entries contain underscores. A simple example is the following table:

```
FirstCol, SecondCol
Item_A, Item_B
```

I am trying to solve my problem with the `csvsimple` package with the "respect underscore=true" option. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|}
   \hline
   \csvreader[respect underscore=true, head to column names, 
    late after line=\\\hline]{Test.csv}{}{\FirstCol & \SecondCol}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following result:

[image]

How do I get rid of the obviously wrong column separators just below the table? To be clear, what I would like is this:

[image]

Note that the two separators only appear if the "respect underscore=true" option is present. If I remove this option (and delete the underscores from the input file), then all works as expected.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204488/csvsimple-handles-underscores-wrong). The latter question was concerned with the underscore not being rendered properly; the present question is concerned with the unwanted column separators appended just under the table.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't like being inside a table.  Try `\csvreader[longtable={|l|l|},table head=\hline,respect underscore=true,head to column names,late after line=\\\hline]{test.csv}{}{\FirstCol & \SecondCol}` instead.

Answer (score 3):

A solution could be `pgfplotstable` with the `verb string type` option.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Test.csv}
    FirstCol, SecondCol
    Item_A, Item_B
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{Test.csv}{\mytable}

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        begin table={\begin{longtable}},
        every head row/.append style={before row={%
                \hline
                \endfirsthead
                \hline
                FirstCol & SecondCol\\
                \hline
                \endhead
            },
        },      
        after row=\hline,       
        end table={\end{longtable}},
        every first column/.style={column type={|l|}},
        every column/.style={column type={l|}},
        verb string type
        ]{\mytable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If at all possible, I would prefer to stay with the `csvsimple` package. We are using it in all our documents and we have developed macros and commands around it. Also, I do not see why it should not be possible to make it work (unless there is a bug in the package, of course).